# Find specific file by last modified date and text inside the file

Tags: c#, file, search, directory

I must find file with last modified date and containing specific text pattern on line 3 of the file.

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\test");
var dispenser = directory.GetFiles("Dispenser*")
                         .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
                         .First();
dispenser.CopyTo("..\\..\\Dispenser", true);
dispenserCopy = true;
```

This returns first file that has filename starting with 'Dispenser' and last modified date. How can I check if on line 3 it has specific text? And if it does not - check the next 'Dispenser*' file (by descending modified date) and so on, and so on, until there is one with text on line 3?

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorting an entire collection just to get the max or min item makes me very uncomfortable...

Comment: @MatthewWatson the task is to search in the collection next, so it is ok.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly Ah yes indeed. I see that one of the answers below do indeed use the sorted collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: edited to attempt to match what I believe you're trying to achieve. That being said - in your place I would honestly take a step back and rethink the approach of using string operations on fixed line numbers against XML data.

```
var dispenser =
   directory.GetFiles("Dispenser*")
            .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
            .Where(f => (File.ReadLines(f.FullName)
                             .Skip(2)
                             .FirstOrDefault()
                               ?? String.Empty).Contains("MY_EXPECTED_LINE"))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Nope - it does nothing if last modified Dispenser* file doesn't have line 3 or "My_expexted_line" in line 3.

Comment: I think this will blow up if there's less than 3 lines in a file - perhaps some check needed for that? Perhaps use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead (probably in both places where `First()` is currently used)

Comment: @MatthewWatson when writing code to SO I tend to modify the OP's code as little as possible to avoid confusing matters; you are correct that in this case it's far more likely to have an empty sequence - corrected

Comment: @Vans - could you expand on 'does nothing'? I'm fairly certain before the edit it might have thrown an exception if the last modified file had less than 3 lines, but that's not something I'd personally call 'does nothing'

Can you give it a go now? If it still does not suit your needs, could you provide more info about what is wrong?

Comment: @decPL do not use `Where`. You will check every file. Use `FirstOrDefault(f => File...);` instead

Comment: @decPC - when I try to copy dispenser with dispenser.CopyTo("..\\..\\Dispenser", true); it gives an exception - Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly absolutely untrue - run the following to verify: `Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Where(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); return i >= 3; }).FirstOrDefault();` LINQ's deffered execution is your friend here

Comment: @Vans that would mean that there is no file satisfying the condition `third line is exactly "MY_EXPECTED_LINE"`

Comment: @decPL - this is the Dispenser file but it still gives me exception: http://s27.postimg.org/9q24y9v7n/Capture.jpg  I copied whole line 3 (with empty spaces in front) - still gives the exception

Comment: @Vans Any chance you could run the following and see what it gives you: `var foundThirdLine = File.ReadLines(MANUAL_PATH_TO_YOUR_TEST_FILE).Skip(2).FirstOrDefault()?? String.Empty;`

Comment: @decPL Oh, I found my mistake - I have mistyped something in the search condition! Sorry for that! And thanks for the solution!!! :)